# Is there a better way to connect a NodeList to multiple events on Dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to set focus and keyup events to the result of a query. I want that each event links to a different method. I made it work like this:

```
query('td').on('focus', tdFocus);
query('td').on('keyup', tdKeyUp);
```

I know I can also do like:

```
query('td').on('focus, keyup', tdEvent);
```

and then I would treat both events in the method (or call the apropriate method with an if or something. But I think there should be a better way to do this.

But I feel there should be a better way to do this. Anyone knows a better way ? like doing one query only and set both events to 2 different methods ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "cache" the result of the query and keep separated your event handlers (KISS ) example:

```
var myQuery= query('td');
myQuery.on('focus', tdFocus);
myQuery.on('keyup', tdKeyUp);
```

Advantages:

- Only one query to the DOM (which is good for performance).
- Clean code as you keep it simple, using a separated callback for each listener instead of one "fat" callback  which need to handle all event listeners internally  using `switch` or `if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

As a suggestion, you can create your own class (using declare) or custom code (as snippet) that attach event to node and it's corresponding execution function, by declaring an array of `{event, function}` object.

You can find all dojo events here: [dojo events](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/quickstart/events.html), also 
Please consider my suggestion snippet Below:

```js
require(["dojo/query","dojo/on","dojo/mouse","dijit/form/TextBox","dojo/ready","dojo/parser"],
    function(query,On,mouse,TextBox,ready){
       ready(function(){
            /*events function */
          var onFocus = function(evt) {
                console.log("onFocus");
            };
            
            var onKeyUp = function(evt) {
             console.log("onKeyUp");
            };
            
            var onMouseEnter = function(evt) {
             console.log("MouseEnter");
            };
      
            /*array containg event type and it's coresponding function */
            event_array = [{event:"focusin",action:onFocus},
                 {event:"keyup",action:onKeyUp},
                           {event:mouse.enter,action:onMouseEnter}];  
   
            /* atach event function */
     var attachEvents = function(node, events) {
             if(typeof(events.forEach) == "function") {
               events.forEach(function(elment){
                  typeof(elment.action) == "function" ? On(node,elment.event,elment.action) : "";
                })
              };
            }
      
            
     var node = query(".input"); 
            //call event attach function.
            attachEvents(node,event_array);
            
         
       })
    }
);
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<body class="claro">
input one  &nbsp; <input class="input" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" /> <br>
input two  &nbsp; <input class="input" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" /> <br>
input three <input class="input" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" /> <br>
</body>
```

You can find also here the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/ravvwrgz/1/)